# How to prevent change in a listbox selected item when users click and move mouse before mouseup

Tags: livecode

I am using the following code in a scrolling field. It works fine in both windows and android. The only problem is that the selected item changes as the mouse mouses up and down the list. I would like the original highlighted line to remain highlighted during the scroll and only change if the mouse have not moves move than 11 units(row height is 22) from initial vertical position. How do I modify this code to achieve that?

```
local lmousev,lvscroll,lscrolling

on mousedown

   --If we don't use lscrolling the list will scroll when the mouse hovers over it 
   put true into lscrolling

   --Set the initial vertical position of the cursor
   put the mousev into lmousev

   --Set the inital position of the vertical scroll
   put the dgvscroll of me into lvscroll 

end mousedown


on mousemove x,y

   if lscrolling=true then --lscrolling is only true after mousedown so no scroll when mouse hovers over

      --adjust the scroll position based on the vertical distance that the mouse has moved since mousedown
      set the dgvscroll of me to lvscroll -(y - lmousev)

   end if

end mousemove


on mouseUp

   --stop scrolling when mouse hovers
   put false into lscrolling


   If abs( the mousev-lmousev)<11 then --If vertival position of mouse has not moved far from vertical position at mousedown

      --selectlist command is in the group. It insert list selection into the textbox 
      selectlist

  end if

end mouseUp

on mouserelease

   --stop scrolling when mouse is release outside the listbox and there is no mouseup
   put false into lscrolling

end mouserelease
```

The button,textbox and listbox that forms the combobox are grouped.The code to show/hide listbox and add selected to textbox is in the group script as follows:

**Additional Info**

```
local ldrop=false

on buttonclick --show/hide the listbox

   --Get the name of the group,textbox & listbox. 
   --Naming convention required:- textboxname=txt & groupName,listboxname=lst & groupname
   --Using quote as deliminater allows us to get the groupname from group "groupname"
   set the itemdel to quote
   put item 2 of the name of me into groupname
   put "lst" & groupname into lstName
   put "txt" & groupname into txtName

   --status of ldrop let us know if the listbox is visible
   if ldrop=false then

      --show listbox 
      set the visible of field lstName to true
      put true into ldrop

   else

       --hide listbox 
      set the visible of field lstName to false
      put false into ldrop

      end if

end buttonclick

on selectlist

   --Get the name of the group,textbox & listbox. 
   --Naming convention required:- textboxname=txt & groupName,listboxname=lst & groupname
   --Using quote as deliminater allows us to get the groupname from group "groupname"
   set the itemdel to quote
   put item 2 of the name of me into groupname
   put "lst" & groupname into lstName
   put "txt" & groupname into txtName


   put the hilitedLine of field lstName into lhilitedLine
   put line lhilitedLine of field lstName  into field txtName
   set the visible of field lstName to false
   put false into ldrop

end selectlist
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make your own control that acts like a list so that you can control all the messages it sends and receives.  You are otherwise stuck with some of those basic functions of LC's built-in controls.  seems like you'd need an engine-level tweak to the control.